# Next JS Firebase hosting html and data here but no stylesheet and some scripts have 404 ERROR

Tags: next.js, firebase-hosting

I am on a journey to deploy my first next app on firebase.... what a headache?! Somehow I managed to deploy it but now I am facing a bunch of issues.

I have styled my components with bootstrap and sass and I am fetching my images and data from an url/public api.

The page load with all the data but no styling and no pictures displayed. When I check the console there are a few errors related to some get requests that get 404 responses. Checking the network tab it shows that my css files have not loaded as well as some scripts.

I don't know what part of code to share as I just don't know what is wrong. I have added some screenshot of related issues, I hope this helps.

Can someone tell me what I should do?

thanks Leo [![console network tab[image: ][1]]][css]

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "crypto-react",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "export": "^0.1.337",
    "next": "^12.0.4-canary.4",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "sharp": "^0.29.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.3"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
//const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');



module.exports = {
  distDir: 'build',
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
    loader: 'custom',
    path: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/',
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  //...
}
```

Comment: mind posting `firebase.json` file?

Comment: Hi @PsyGik thanks for your time. i edited my question with code

Comment: Are you using `next export` or is your site using Server rendering (`next build & next start`)?

Comment: @Psygik i tried with next export bun ran into issues related to next/image so i had to remove it. as we speak i run build without next export

Comment: Firebase Hosting only accepts static files. `next build && next start` is a NodeJS server, so you need to deploy it using Cloud Functions or a provider like Vercel. Next.js has provided a sample here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting.

Comment: @PsyGik thanks you so much for that documentation, it might be just what i need. I added my next config and package.json for you to see. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239167/discussion-between-leo-and-psygik).

Comment: Hi all, i have finally find issues to my problem. Thanks you helping @psyGik. My server.js function was wrong and my next config same. Please see below how in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
//const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
const withImages = require('next-images')


module.exports = withImages(  {
  
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com', 'mywebsite.whatever.com'],
      //  loader: 'imgix',
      //  path: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/',
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  //...
}
)
```

on the server.js uncomment images as follow

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: '.next' },
    //images :{ domain :['assets.coingecko.com'],}
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return server.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res)
        });
});
```

then add a custom loader to my image as follow on the component this supposed to render them

```
const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

<Image
              loader={myLoader}
              className="mr-3"
              src={image}
              alt="crypto"
              height={30}
              width={30}
            />
```

And that it :).

Thank you all for your help. I hope this will someone in the future. :)